# shingle generated tokens are not search against index?

Tags: search, solr, token, analyzer

If I have "ice cube" in my index(record). Now if search "icecube" against shingle field, then it should logically show the results since shingle will create "ice","cube" and "icecube" as three tokens. I can see three token in the debugQuery but results are not shown. Is the shingle token "icecube" getting lost or is it ignored during search ?

Comment: what is your shingle Configuration ??? why would icecube be generated on shingle ?

Comment: Here the schema configuration link: http://pastebin.com/74xaKEyv. I am using shingle here.

Comment: How did you declare the field? Can you add that, as well?

Comment: <field name="title" type="text_prime" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" omitNorms="false" multiValued="false" />

Comment: any updates. Please help me. I am stuck here.